# Help with a general solution for $\int \tan^a \theta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Working out the integrals of $\tan^6 \theta$ I saw a pattern.  I would like to put it in series representation. The pattern is as follows:

$$\int \tan^a d\theta= \int\tan^{a-2}\theta(\sec^2\theta-1)\ d\theta= $$ $$ \int \tan ^{a-2}\theta\sec^2\theta\ d\theta-\int\tan^{a-2}\theta\ d\theta=$$ solving the first integral, let $u=\tan \theta, du=\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$ so $$ \int u^{a-2} du=\frac{1}{a-2+1}u^{a-2+1}=$$ $$\frac{1}{a-1}u^{a-1}= $$$$\frac{1}{a-1}\tan^{a-1}\theta-\int \tan^{a-2}\theta\ d\theta $$

then $$ \int u^{(a-2)-2} du=\frac{1}{(a-2)-1}u^{(a-2)-1}=$$ $$\frac{1}{a-3}u^{a-3}= $$$$\frac{1}{a-3}\tan^{a-3}\theta-\int \tan^{a-4}\theta\ d\theta $$ It goes on like this forever

$$\frac{1}{a-1}\tan^{a-1}\theta-\frac{1}{a-3}\tan^{a-3}\theta-\frac{1}{a-5}\tan^{a-5}\theta \text {....} \theta\ d\theta $$ So then my series should be....$$\frac{1}{a-1}\tan^{a-1}\theta-\big[\sum_{n=3}^{a-2} {\frac{1}{a-n}\tan^{a-n}\theta}\big] -\int \tan^{2}\theta\ d\theta\space \text{if a is even. OR}$$

$$\frac{1}{a-1}\tan^{a-1}\theta-\big[\sum_{n=3}^{a-2} {\frac{1}{a-n}\tan^{a-n}\theta}\big] -\int \tan\ d\theta\space \text{if a is odd}.$$

I am having problems tweaking this series so it only includes the odd values of "n"?

$addendum$

For those not reading the entire thread as discussed below. the value of n is $n=2k-1$. 
The lower limit should be $k=1$ and the upper limit should be $\frac {a}{2}-1$ for even "a"'s and $\frac {a-1}{2}$ for odd. Thanks again to SemSem.

Comment: @Semsem I "a" starts out odd the series ends at a=1 if a it starts even the series ends at a=2 ( odd-2 is odd) (even -2 is even) This pattern in the residual integral does not change. It will either be $\int\tan^2\theta$ or $\int\tan\theta$

Comment: Hi, a few points about how this site works. If you don't think that the answer below actually answers the question, you can untick the green check mark, and add a comment to the answer stating that the answer does not completely answer the question. Note that a built-in software limitation means that as long as the green check mark is ticked, even if Semsem wanted to delete his answer, he cannot do so. Lastly, moderators expressly do not play judge on whether answers are correct (in their capacity as moderators).

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you, it actually worked out better the other way. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you have
$$I_a=\int \tan^a d\theta= \int\tan^{a-2}(\sec^2-1)d\theta
\\=\frac{1}{a-1}\tan^{a-1}\theta-\int \tan^{a-2} d\theta
\\ I_a=\frac{1}{a-1}\tan^{a-1}\theta-I_{a-2}$$from this last one you can start by applying it many times to get your required formula. If $n$ is even we get
$$I_a=\frac{1}{a-1}\tan^{a-1}\theta-\frac{1}{a-3}\tan^{a-3}\theta+ \frac{1}{a-5}\tan^{a-5}\theta ....I_{2}
\\=\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\frac{a}{2}-1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{a-(2k-1)}\tan^{a-(2k-1)}\theta+(-1)^{\frac{a}{2}}I_2$$ 
If $n$ is odd we get
$$I_a=\frac{1}{a-1}\tan^{a-1}\theta-\frac{1}{a-3}\tan^{a-3}\theta+ \frac{1}{a-5}\tan^{a-5}\theta ....I_{1}
\\=\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\frac{a-1}{2}}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{a-(2k-1)}\tan^{a-(2k-1)}\theta+(-1)^{\frac{a+1}{2}}I_2$$

Comment: I saw that it should read $(a-2)-2$ and $(a-2)-2+1$ and edited it. Please keep comments in the comments. How do I adjust the series?

Comment: I have deleted my comment, you still have a simple problem, in all cases your last calculation will give $a-(a-2)=2$ , it will never be 1 !!!.@Chris

Comment: It did not delete. But you were correct, so I moved it to comments.

Comment: @Chris i am trying with you to fix this formula to include both even and odd numbers

Comment: Thank you, but as I said the "n"'s in the solution are ALWAYS odd BUT the way the series is now I get a-3, a-4, a-5.... I want to tweak the SERIES part of the solution so that "n" is always odd (3,5,7,9.....).

Comment: @Chris this one for even, revise it please i will repair one for odd

Comment: Had to do it in two equations in the edit

Comment: I am strictly looking at the series notation. Which is the series you just put up. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Whenever we use your 'recurrence' we are left with an integral likes, for example,
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\mu}\tan^{a}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}$ where $\ds{0 \leq \verts{\Re\pars{a}} < 1}$ and, because $\ds{\tan\pars{\theta}}$is periodic of period $\ds{\pi}$, $\ds{0 < \mu < \pi}$.

> With $\ds{t \equiv \sin\pars{\theta}}$ and $\ds{\Lambda = \sin\pars{\mu}}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\mu}\tan^{a}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta&=\int_{0}^{\mu}
> {\sin^{a}\pars{\theta} \over \cos^{a + 1}\pars{\theta}}\,\cos\pars{\theta}\dd\theta
> =-\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{t^{a} \over \pars{1 - t^{2}}^{a/2 + 1/2}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\int_{0}^{\Lambda^{1/2}}
> {t^{a/2} \over \pars{1 - t}^{a/2 + 1/2}}\,\half\,t^{-1/2}\,\dd t
> =-\,\half\int_{0}^{\Lambda^{1/2}}t^{a/2 - 1/2}\pars{1 - t}^{-a/2 - 1/2}
> \,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\,{\rm B}_{\Lambda^{1/2}}\pars{{a \over 2} + \half,-\,{a \over 2} + \half}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm B}_{x}\pars{p,q}}$ is the [Incomplete Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).

$$
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\mu}\tan^{a}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
=
-\,\half\,{\rm B}_{\root{\sin\pars{\mu}}}
\pars{{a \over 2} + \half,-\,{a \over 2} + \half}}\,,\quad
\left\vert%
\begin{array}{c}
\quad\verts{\Re\pars{a}} < 1
\\[2mm]
\quad0 < \mu <  \pi
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Haven't heard of Beta Functions (Something else to learn thank you.) Higher math does make things simpler... most of the time. In the mean time this works also. Yes, when ever you run this recurrent series you are left with some integral of $\tan\theta$ but it will either be $tan^2\theta$ or $\tan\theta$ and those integrals are well known.